# How to command cmd using VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba, cmd

I wanted to open CMD via Excel using VBA.

When it opens It should write on the command line;

```
"runAnalysis bendingResult/Sample1.csv bendingResult/SampleResult1.csv"
```

When executed the cmd closes when the run is finished.

I usually have to type the above but I want to automate it on CMD using Excel VBA.

I used this to open the cmd. My code is below :

```
Dim PID
PID = Shell("C:\Analysis\x86\cmd.exe", vbNormalFocus)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
shell ("runAnalysis bendingResult/Sample1.csv bendingResult/SampleResult1.csv")
```

but if you need to use multiple lines for then you need to create a bat file and run it:

```
Dim oFile As Object
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\somepath\somefile.bat")

oFile.WriteLine "C:"
oFile.WriteLine "cd windows"
oFile.WriteLine "dir"
oFile.WriteLine "pause"

oFile.Close

Shell ("C:\somepath\somefile.bat")
```

Comment: i did that on the vba excel. But it keeps on telling me an error . This app can't run to your PC. Is there a way to be not reliant on the Bat file and use pure vba to command the CMD...

Comment: That should be the shell() version.

Comment: so do i need to update my shell? or?

Comment: I don't know what you have so I can't answer that. But have you tried the shell() answer I posted? Possibly it needs the full path of the files.

Comment: I tried your code it seems working it creates the bat file and writes all the necessary writelines I need but running it at the end. it prompts an error.

I am using windows [10] Version 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1466)

Comment: An error... You expecting me to guess?

Comment: All is working now fine mate thank you for your answer! have a nice day